# Is it possible to sum values of arrays stored in a dictionary without for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

So I feel like I might have coded myself into a corner -- but here I am.

I have created a dictionary of arrays (well specifically ascii Columns) because I needed to create five arrays performing the same calculation on an array with five different parameters (The calculation involved multiplying arrays and one of five arbitrary constants).

I now want to create an array where each element corresponds to the sum of the equivalent element from all five arrays. I'd rather not use the ugly for loop that I've created (it's also hard to check if i'm getting the right answer with the loop).

Here is a modified snippet for testing!

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Column
from pylab import *

# The five paramaters for the Columns 
n1 = [14.18,19.09,33.01,59.73,107.19,172.72] #uJy/beam
n2 = [14.99,19.04,32.90,59.99,106.61,184.06] #uJy/beam
n1 = np.array([x*1e-32 for x in n1]) #W/Hz
n2 = np.array([x*1e-32 for x in n2]) #W/Hz


# an example of the arrays being mathed upon
luminosity=np.array([2.393e+24,1.685e+24,2.264e+23,5.466e+22,3.857e+23,4.721e+23,1.818e+23,3.237e+23])
redshift = np.array([1.58,1.825,0.624,0.369,1.247,0.906,0.422,0.66])

field = np.array([True,True,False,True,False,True,False,False])

DMs = {}
for i in range(len(n1)):
    DMs['C{0}'.format(i)]=0

for SC,SE,level in zip(n1,n2,DMs):
    DMmax = Column([1 for x in redshift], name='DMmax')
    DMmax[field]=(((1+redshift[field])**(-0.25))*(luminosity[field]/(4*pi*5*SE))**0.5)*3.24078e-23
    DMmax[~field]=(((1+redshift[~field])**(-0.25))*(luminosity[~field]/(4*pi*5*SC))**0.5)*3.24078e-23
    DMs[level] = DMmax
```

Thanks all!

Comment: can you make a simpler example of what you are trying to achieve?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need a loop to sum all values of a collection. There really is no other way

Comment: for dict named **d** how about **sum(d.values())**

Comment: I did try that, and many variations. `sum(d.values())` doesn't work. It appears to sum all values of all columns. I can also do (e.g.) `sum(d.values()[2])`, but this sums all values of all columns from index 2 onward. I tried messing around with stuff like `sum(d.values()[:0])`, but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy was built for this! (provided all arrays are of the same shape)

Just add them, and numpy will move element-wise through the arrays. This also has the benefit of being orders of magnitude faster than using a for-loop in the Python layer.

Example:

```
>>> n1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> n2 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> total = n1 + n2
>>> total
array([2,4,6])
>>> mask = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> n1[mask] ** n2[mask]
array([ 1, 27])
```

**Edit** additional input

You might be able to do something like this:

```
SE_array = (((1+redshift[field]) ** (-0.25)) * (luminosity[field]/(4*pi*5*n1[field])) ** 0.5) * 3.24078e-23
SC_array = (((1+redshift[field]) ** (-0.25)) * (luminosity[field]/(4*pi*5*n2[field])) ** 0.5) * 3.24078e-23
```

and make the associations by stacking the new arrays:

```
DM = np.dstack((SE_array, SC_array))
reshaper = DM.shape[1:]    # take from shape (1, 6, 2) to (6,2), where 6 is the length of the arrays
DM = DM.reshape(reshaper)
```

This will give you a 2d array like:

```
array([[SE_1, SC_1],
       [SE_2, SC_2]])
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about stacking or reshaping! This is super helpful, thanks @willnx

Answer (score 1):

If you can't just add the numpy arrays you can extract the creation of the composite array into a function.

```
def get_element(i):
    global n1, n2, luminosity, redshift, field

    return n1[i] + n2[i] + luminosity[i] + redshift[i] + field[i]

L = len(n1)
composite = [get_element(i) for i in range(L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was staring at me in the face, but thanks to @willnx, @cricket_007, and @andrew-lavq. Your suggestions made me realise how simple the solution is.

> Just add them, and numpy will move element-wise through the arrays. -- willnx
>
> You need a loop to sum all values of a collection -- cricket_007

so it really is as simple as

`sum(x for x in DMs.values())`

I'm not sure if this is the fastest solution, but I think it's the simplest.